# How can I set accelerator shortcuts on CheckBoxMenuItems in Java?

Tags: java, checkbox, keyboard-shortcuts, awt, menuitem

I'm writing a simple drawing program in Java, and I've got a MenuBar (not a JMenuBar) to select the shapes and colors to be drawn.  I want to set keyboard shortcuts to select between Rectangle, Oval, and Line.  I know I can use MenuShortcut for MenuItems, but this doesn't work for CheckBoxMenuItems.  Any clue how I can accomplish this?

Comment: *"a simple drawing program in Java"*  Doing it using AWT will not be 'simple' for two reasons.  1) AWT has less functionality than Swing (you have to 'roll your own' more often) 2) The few people who used AWT have largely forgotten it. -- That your professor demands AWT components *now,* is a very (***very***) bad sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this needs a [`JRadioButtonMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButtonMenuItem.html) given the user will be drawing one of the elements at a time  (e.g. what is an Oval-Line?).

`JRadioButtonMenuItem` has an accelerator.  E.G.

[image: Radio Menu Demo]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RadioMenuDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel();

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu shapes = new JMenu("Draw");
                mb.add(shapes);
                ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
                shapes.setMnemonic('D');

                JRadioButtonMenuItem line = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Line");
                line.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("L"));
                shapes.add(line);
                bg.add(line);

                JRadioButtonMenuItem oval = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Oval");
                oval.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("O"));
                shapes.add(oval);
                bg.add(oval);

                JRadioButtonMenuItem rect = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Rectangle");
                rect.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("R"));
                shapes.add(rect);
                bg.add(rect);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Radio menu items");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setJMenuBar(mb);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is basically a radiobutton (using if statements to disable the others), but I'm using a regular MenuBar and not a JMenuBar.  The program I'm writing is just my way to study for my final exam, and my professor doesn't let us use JMenuBar

Comment: *"my professor doesn't let us use JMenuBar"*  Your professor needs to drag themselves (kicking & screaming) into the 3rd millennium, until that time, they should not be teaching others.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree, and as soon as the class is over, I'm going back through all of the projects using Swing instead of AWT, but until Finals are over, I've gotta do what he wants

Comment: +1 for Swing, but I'm surprised that the `setShortcut()` inherited from `MenuItem` doesn't work.